# SharePoint Publish Html field NumLines value not working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am creating a a publishing Html field using below xml. When I retrieve the field after creation also  no of lines field is set to 6. But when the field is rendered in new form it has only one line and not six. Is NumLines value is not considered for publish html field?

```
<Field ID="7aeaf4de-3cb3-48c6-8586-4106290fa12d" DisplayName="FieldDisplayName" Name="FieldName" Group="Group1" Type="HTML" Description="" NumLines="6" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml"></Field>
```

Comment: You can use the `UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary ="TRUE" ` attribute. AFAIK, NumLines will only work on Note Field.

Comment: Will  UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary ="TRUE" will increase the height of the rendered field? Also I'm working with a list, not a library.